# How to remove TR if there is a specific text inside its TD's in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I want to remove the TR if its 2nd TD value is similar to another TRs TD value and it's last TD value shouldn't be HIT. And the another scenario is if I have 3 TRs with the same data then 2 of them should be removed and 1 should remain there.

Example:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Ref No</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Result</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1121</td>
   <td>Joseph</td>
   <td>CLEAR</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>1122</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
   <td>CLEAR</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>1122</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
   <td>CLEAR</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>1122</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
   <td>HIT</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>1123</td>
   <td>Jim</td>
   <td>HIT</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>1124</td>
   <td>James</td>
   <td>CLEAR</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>7</td>
   <td>1124</td>
   <td>James</td>
   <td>CLEAR</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>8</td>
   <td>1124</td>
   <td>James</td>
   <td>CLEAR</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

What I want:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Ref No</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Result</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1121</td>
   <td>Joseph</td>
   <td>CLEAR</td>
</tr>    

<tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>1122</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
   <td>HIT</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>1123</td>
   <td>Jim</td>
   <td>HIT</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>1124</td>
   <td>James</td>
   <td>CLEAR</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this task?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by similar?

Comment: same value as another row... he wants to create a table subset - only rows where 2nd column has only unique values (i think) :)

Comment: @Noah see the example which I've provided. You will get it.

Comment: @flynorc yes you got me right.

Comment: try to start learning javascript programming

Comment: @Banzay I've already learned. I need bit help with this one.

Comment: question... do you have a way to manipulate the source (if the result is for example coming from a database or a file or sth and the output is printed to a table with for example php script)?

Comment: No, it's just I have do it with jquery. @flynorc

Comment: did you give my fiddle a try?

Answer (score 1):

So i made this clumsy answer for you. You can check it out in the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/flynorc/31vwbn5x/5/).

**EDIT:** after some discussion about what should the behaviour be, i updated the fiddle. so now it adds the check if there are any fields in the duplicates that have a "HIT" value in fourth column it will keep the first row with HIT value, otherwise it will keep the first value for each unique second column value.

I am sure there is a better/simpler/more effective way to do this with jQuery, but that is what I came up with. The basic algorithm is this: get all rows and iterate. For each row: find the value in second td (column), check all subsequent rows, fetch the value in second column there and compare them. if they are the same, remove the duplicate row from DOM.

```
//get the table rows, this should be done with a different selector if there are more tables e.g. with class or id...
$tableRows = $("tr");

//iterate over all elements (rows)
$tableRows.each(function(index, element) {
  var $element = $(element);
  //get the value of the current element
  var currentRowValue = $element.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

  //check all elements that come after the current element if the value matches, if so, remove the matching element
  for (var i = index + 1; i < $tableRows.length; i++) {
    var $rowToCompare = $($tableRows[i]);
    var valueToCompare = $rowToCompare.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

    if(valueToCompare === currentRowValue) {
      //remove the duplicate from dom
      //if the second row (the duplicate) has 4th column of "HIT" then keep the second row and remove the first row
      var duplicateRowFourthColumnVal = $rowToCompare.find("td:nth-child(4)").text();
      if(duplicateRowFourthColumnVal == "HIT") {
        $element.remove();
      }
      else {
        $rowToCompare.remove();
      }
    }
  }
});`
```

Comment: The current fiddle doesn't remove the tr. It only gets the value of the following rows and console logs it.

Comment: You sir are correct. I forgot to update the link
@MarcCompte thank you for noticing. i updated it now.
if you have any ideas on how to improve the solution, please share :)

Comment: The second loop could be done only on the elements returned by the `:contains()` selector. Double checking the values should be necessary (12 would match also 121) but it would iterate fewer times. I don't know if it would mean a noticeably faster performance with large data sets. I don't know if large data sets will be used either.

Comment: @flynorc I tried it, but it didn't fulfill my requirements. :(

Comment: in what way? is this not what you asked for (left part of image before click, right part after)

https://ibb.co/cgUWka

Comment: @FazilMir  in what way? is this not what you asked for (left part of image before click, right part after) ibb.co/cgUWka

Comment: @flynorc but I want to to show only those records which have HIT as their result type (Last Column). 
In the pic, it's showing Mike with result type CLEAR. And i want the one which is HIT.

Comment: @FazilMir well that was not included anywhere in your question. i suggest you read your question and update it to reflect all your wishes and desires. Also why would you remove ALL the 1124 ref nr elements and also all the 1121.

Comment: @flynorc I have mentioned it in my question. What I want is if there are multiple records with same refNo and result type is CLEAR. Then I need to get only of them. And if result type of two records are different eg: refNo=111 Result=Clear and another is refNo=111 Result=Hit. I need to get HIT record. That's it. I appreciate your work. It's just we are so close to achieve this task. If you could help me more.

Comment: i'm a bit confused. should the "CLEAR" rows be cleared first (no matter if they are duplicates or not), and then the duplicates removed?

OR should the "CLEAR"  rows be removed only when they are a duplicate of another row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135223/discussion-between-flynorc-and-fazil-mir).